# Selecting specific csv files by pattern to be merged

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have several csv files at a folder, and their names are as follow:

```
xxy_1_2020_3_4_Cause_effect_pairs.csv
asd_3_2025_4_5_none.csv
sdp_2_2302_3_4_Cause_effect_pairs.csv
```

Out of all these files, I am trying to get files that has "Cause_effect_pairs" in the name. and in the next stage I will merge them.

```
import os, re
files = os.listdir('../output')

samples, references = [], []
for file in files:
    if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]{1,6}_\d{1,2}_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}_Cause_Effect_Pairs', file):
        references.append(file)
    elif re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]{1,6}_\d{1,2}_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}_Missed_verbs', file):
        samples.append(file)
    else:
        print('{0} is neither sample nor reference'.format(file))
```

I got this error :

```
.ipynb_checkpoints is neither sample nor reference
```

Comment: `.ipynb_checkpoints` is a file in directory, not seen to be an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator?

```
for file in all_filenames:
    if 'Cause_effect_pairs' in file:
        print(file)
```